# Are there any drivers for Canon i450 Printer for OSX 10.7?

Tags: macos, printing, canon

My computer sees the printer and it looks like it installed, but when I try to print, I get an error message that it can't find a print head or that the print head is busy.

Comment: Apple typically bundle the drivers and provide updates to drivers through the normal Apple software update process. Are there any software updates available? My guess is it's a hardware error / condition on the printer, but since you asked for drivers, that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I have the same problem with Mountain Lion.